# Amd catalyst drivers increases screen contrast if laptop is on battery power

Tags: ati, brightness, catalyst

How to prevent catalyst drivers from increasing contrast if I switch from power supply to battery power? One oddity about this is that increase in contrast isn't shown in the drivers settings, e.g. if contrast is set to 80, then the number stays 80, but contrast is still messed up while on battery power.
Another problem is that even if I then manually try to decrease contrast to about 50...60 then the screen still doesn't look quite right.